# PACKAGE_VERSION conflicts of multiple config.h in both library and application

Tags: c++, c, autoconf

When using `autoconf` tool, the package-related M4 macros get defined by `AC_INIT` and stored in `config.h`, of which some are listed below:

- `PACKAGE`
- `PACKAGE_NAME`
- `PACKAGE_TARNAME`
- `PACKAGE_VERSION`
- `PACKAGE_STRING`

Most of my library include files uses this `config.h` file which is stored in its own installed include subdirectory (i.e., `/usr/include/mylib`).

Enters my application program, it uses this same library's include files.

Also, this application program has its own `configure.ac`/`AC_INIT` and, in turn, generates its own `config.h` locally as well.

At compile times, I get these warning messages:

```
In file include from app.cpp:3:0:
config.h:427:0 warning: "PACKAGE_VERSION" redefined
 #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.2"
 ^
In file included from <command-line>:0:0:
/usr/include/mylib/config.h:535:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "4.0"
```

What's the best way in dealing with this conflict of multiple `AC_INIT`-generated PACKAGE macro group?

Answer (score 2):

> Most of my library include files uses this config.h file which is stored in its own installed include subdirectory (i.e., /usr/include/mylib).

It's not a good idea to install `config.h` for exactly the problem you encountered.  There's a few ways to excise `config.h` from your include files.  One way is:

```
#if BUILDING_MYLIB
#include "config.h"
#endif

...
```

Then deal with other dependencies as you find them when building your application.

Comment: Basically, I've ported an existing library which used PACKAGE.  Looks like I'm going to have to painstakingly modify each and every library's include files to do this.

Is it OK to hold out for a possible solution rather than a 'it shouldn't have been done' answer?

Comment: You should find out what it is you need out of `config.h` for your header files.  I would hope that they wouldn't need `PACKAGE`, etc. to be defined.  If your headers don't need anything out of `config.h` then, it's pretty easy to excise `config.h`, and add it to your lib's source files.  It's often not the case, though unfortunately.